# What is the difference between "directrice exécutive" and "directrice générale"

Tags: choix-de-mot

When translating for "Executive Director", are both acceptable?

Answer (score 3):

**Directeur exécutif (EB)/ Président directeur général (PDG)**

Il s’agit du poste principal au sein d’une organisation. Le directeur exécutif (dans les organisations de plus grande taille, ce poste est souvent appelé directeur général) relève directement du comité de direction, par l’intermédiaire du président du comité. L’autorité suprême relative aux opérations de l’organisation revient aux directeurs exécutifs ou généraux. Selon le style de gouvernance du conseil, le directeur exécutif ou général supervise habituellement les activités quotidiennes et le conseil d’administration est chargé de l’orientation politique et de la surveillance.

Dans une petite organisation, un directeur exécutif pourrait réaliser des activités très concrètes, en assumant la gestion de la collecte de fonds/de la rédaction des demandes de subventions, la gestion financière, les ressources humaines et l’élaboration et la gestion des programmes, et pourrait même participer activement aux activités de l’organisation.

Dans une organisation de plus grande taille, le directeur exécutif ou général est souvent éloigné d’un cran des activités et joue un rôle de superviseur auprès du personnel de la haute direction qui assume les fonctions. Dans ce cas, le directeur exécutif ou général s’assure que le travail est réalisé correctement et dans les délais, que l’on assume les responsabilités par rapport aux fournisseurs de fonds et que l’on respecte les obligations fiscales, et que la direction de l’organisme va de l’avant.

So in **conclusion**, yes “directrice exécutive“ and “directrice générale” can both be used whan talking about an "Executive Director" in english.

[Source](https://www.rondpointdelitinerance.ca/solutions/directeur-ex%C3%A9cutif-eb-pr%C3%A9sident-directeur-g%C3%A9n%C3%A9ral-pdg)

*Note: Sorry for writing it in french but it would make no sense to me to explain it in english, as in english it seems you only have 1 word to describe it. If you have any question about the translation or anything feel free to ask in the comments below :)*

Comment: Thank you.  Each time I have used the word directrice exécutive as the translation for Executive Director,  the translation service I use has corrected it to directrice générale. I just wondered if the first is not proper or if the latter is more precise.

Comment: You're welcome, He is the one that takes important decision within  the company, both appellations have the same meanings.

Answer (score 2):

**Non**, *directrice exécutive* est un anglicisme car l'adjectif [exécutif](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=4240) « s'applique, en français, à ce qui est relatif à la mise en œuvre des lois et à leur exécution » ([BDL](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=1299292)) ce qui n'a rien à voir avec ce dont il s'agit ici. C'est la raison pour laquelle le service de traduction que tu utilisais rejetait avec raison cette appellation, quoiqu'on la retrouve dans la [francophonie](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-fra.html?lang=fra&i=1&srchtxt=EXECUTIVE%20DIRECTOR&index=alt&codom2nd_wet=1#resultrecs) vu l'influence de la langue anglaise dans le monde des affaires. On préférera plutôt formellement de *chef de la direction* ou de *directrice générale* et on se fiera à des sources crédibles.

Comment: Je me demande néanmoins si les termes *directeur général* ou *Président directeur général (PDG)* ne seraient pas plus utilisés que *chef de la direction*